# Custom framework using SpriteKit - asset files not loaded

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ios-frameworks, asset-catalog

I created a cocoa touch framework project, which uses SpriteKit and includes image assets. (It's a framework because the idea is to create a mini game that I can add to different apps).
I am testing it with a sample project that uses this framework.
My problem is at runtime - when I create a sprite with an image I get an error:

SKTexture: Error loading image resource XXXXX

I am using SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"XXXXXX").
the images are in the bundle of the framework in a folder. I tried also putting them in an asset catalog. nothing works.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: I tried creating a UIImage with and image from the framework and it worked because I used:
UIImage(named:in:compatibleWith:) and gave it Bundle(for: type(of: self)).
I Wish there was some way to pass the framework bundle when creating SKSprite or SKTexture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you can get the desired asset from the framework as a UIImage, couldn't you just

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image", in: type(of: self), compatibleWith: nil) 
let texture = SKTexture(image: image)
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

Comment: Yes, I actually did that in order for things to work, but I think it's performance consuming and very bad practice. isn't it?